# How can I see if Cloudflare is minifying my HTML, CSS and JS properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagespeed, cloudflare

I'm trying out Cloudflare and am under the impression (after what I've read) that the service should minify my HTML, CSS and JS to I don't have to do this manually for my files before I publish them.

In the performance settings, I've enabled Auto Minify (Web optimization) for HTML, CSS and JS

But when I visit my site in Google Chrome and click on View Source, the HTML is not minified. If I go to www.domain.com/style.css or /javascript.js it's not minified either.

Have I missunderstood how it should work or isn't Cloudflare working properly for me? How does your sites using cloudflare look if you view source in browser?

Comment: Have you consulted their support and documentation? For example, [Why isn't Auto Minify working?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169876-Why-isn-t-Auto-Minify-working-) and [How do I minify HTML, CSS and JavaScript to optimize my site?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168196-How-do-I-minify-HTML-CSS-and-JavaScript-to-optimize-my-site-)

Comment: @Rasmus Lindström   so what did you find?  I'm hitting the same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like we are not proxying the record. The feature does require that our proxy be running over the record in your DNS settings for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I posted a question in the form on the page "Boaz" was linking to in the comment on my first post. Hope the support will be able to find the correct answer now when they have the URL and can view the account. Thanks again / Rasmus